# How to add a Poisson distribution curve that approaches 3?

Tags: r, plot, poisson

I want to add a curve to an existing plot.
This curve should be a poisson distribution curve that approaches the mean 3.

I've tried this code
points is a vector with 1000 values

```
plot(c(1:1000), points,type="l")
abline(h=3)
x = 0:1000
curve(dnorm(x, 3, sqrt(3)), lwd=2, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

I am getting a plot, but without any curve. 
I would like to see a curve that approaches 3.

Comment: A Poisson distribution with mean 3 looks like `plot(0:10, dpois(0:10, 3), type = 'b')`. You could add it to an existing plot with `lines(0:10, dpois(0:10, 3))`. I'm not sure if that's what you want though, can you try to explain how the curve "approaches 3"?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
plot(0:20, 3+dpois( x=0:20, lambda=3 ), xlim=c(-2,20))
normden <- function(x){3+dnorm(x, mean=3, sd=sqrt(3))}
curve(normden, from=-4, to=20, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

running this code will produce the following:

is that what you intended?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the curve approaches 0 not 3

Comment: you want it to be shifted from the 0-line to 3-line? im not sure I understand what exactly do you want, can you elaborate

Comment: Yes exactly, I want it to be shifted to 3-line!

Comment: now it is with bias of 3, so its just the same code shifted